# How to get LibreOffice Help installed for the AppImage version of LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, appimage

OS: Kubuntu 18.04

I downloaded the basic, fresh LibreOffice AppImage using

```
aria2c "https://libreoffice.soluzioniopen.com/stable/fresh/LibreOffice-fresh.basic-x86_64.AppImage"
```

I moved the file to *~/bin* and made it executable. It works just fine.

However, when I press <kbd>F1</kbd> to access *Help*, I get the following window:

[image: Help not available]

What more do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downloading

https://libreoffice.soluzioniopen.com/stable/fresh/LibreOffice-fresh.basic-x86_64.AppImage

I should have installed
    https://libreoffice.soluzioniopen.com/stable/fresh/LibreOffice-fresh.basic.help-x86_64.AppImage

This version is the LibreOffice AppImage with *Help* available off-line. The difference is that it's being accessed via the browser, Google Chrome, in my case, and not from with LibreOffice itself (as happens when one installs a repository version or via a ppa).

Sample urls showing in the browser's address bar:

```
file:///tmp/.mount_LibreOdssV6p/opt/libreoffice6.1/help/en-US/text/swriter/01/02110100.html?DbPAR=WRITER#bm_id3155338  
file:///tmp/.mount_LibreOdssV6p/opt/libreoffice6.1/help/en-US/text/swriter/main0000.html?DbPAR=WRITER
```

In other words, if you want to access LibreOffice's Help offline via your browser use the download link that has `.help` in it.