# How can I make an AppImage show for all local users in the applications listing?

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, appimage, multi-user

This question is similar to:

- [kdenlive appimage file: how to get it to show in list of applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/1066664/457111)

However, I want to install my AppImages for ALL users on the computer (it's a family laptop), not just for me.  I'd like to do this without having to modify anything inside anyone else's home directory.

In other words, just as I can install e.g. a new game via Muon Package Manager and have it immediately available to all other users if they go to "Applications -> Games" in the Application Launcher, I'd like to accomplish the same effect for packages (software) that I download as AppImages.

(I'm using Kubuntu 20.04.)

I am pretty sure I'll need to make the AppImage file executable and move it to some directory that's owned by root, but I'm not sure where.  I'll also probably need to add a `.desktop` file in some other directory owned by root but I'm not sure where this should be either, or what needs to be in it.

How can I make an installed AppImage into a "first-class citizen" as far as showing in all users' application launchers is concerned?

Comment: I did succeed in doing this; will have to write up a self-answer sometime.